# Boost unit test link error

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

I just started using 'boost test' for C++ unit tests in a Windows environment (Visual Studio 2010). I'm following this tutorial as a guide:

http://legalizeadulthood.wordpress.com/2009/07/04/c-unit-tests-with-boost-test-part-1/
But after including the boost `unit_test.hpp` file, it shows the compile error below:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_unit_test_framework-vc100-mt-gd-1_52.lib'
```

My source code is like this:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MAIN
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
```

Please assist with ideas on how to solve this.

Comment: yes, link to the libboost_unit_test_framework-vc100-mt-gd-1_52.lib library

Comment: @BЈовић - here it recommended to use 'not use precompiled headers' option. So I don't think it need lib files to be linked

Comment: looks like you are trying to link, but the linker can not find it. That is what the error says. I'd check the search paths for the linker

Comment: @BЈовић - Is this lib file include in boost? And Which path I need to add to the liker 'Additional Library Directories'?

Comment: sorry, no idea how is that for for windows. you should check linking options

Comment: If you really want to use Boost.Test without linking to any libraries, you need to use `#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>` instead of your `#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>`. However I believe that this will result in longer compilation times than you would get if you use the libraries.

Comment: @llonesmiz - Thank you, This method also works. but with a warning `warning C4535: calling _set_se_translator() requires /EHa`. Any idea about warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this issue by two steps.

1. build boost by using command prompt. instructions check [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#or-simplified-build-from-source)
2. Add "boost_1_52_0\stage\lib" to project propert->Linker->Library path